# Integral Question $\int\frac{\sin^4(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx$

Tags: integration

What you are suggesting to do?

Convert $\sin^4(x)\Rightarrow (1-\cos^2(x))^2\,dx?$
$$ ∫\frac{\sin^4(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$

Thanks!

Comment: Follow that impulse: on completing the "long division", do you get integrals you _can_ work out?

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question, so what do you want?

Comment: I tried to convert and didnt solve it, so I`m asking if there is another way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea will produce $$\int \frac{1 \ - \ 2 \cos^2 x \ + \ \cos^4 x}{\cos^2 x} \ dx  =  \int \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} \ - \ \frac{2 \cos^2 x}{\cos^2 x} \ + \ \frac{\cos^4 x}{\cos^2 x} \ dx $$

$$ =  \int \sec^2 x \ - \ 2 \ + \ \cos^2 x \ dx \ . \ $$

Does that seem more manageable?

[Note: if you haven't already seen it, there is a trig identity to use on that last integral:  $\cos^2 x  \ = \ \frac{1}{2} (1 + \cos 2x) $ .]

Answer (score 3):

$\sin^4(x) = (1-\cos^2(x))^2=1-2 \cos^2(x)+\cos^4(x)$, hence your integral turns into three simple integrals:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\cos^2(x)}\\
\int dx\\
\int \cos^2(x)dx
$$
I'll help you with the last one: denote $I=\int \cos^2 (x) dx, \ J=\int \sin^2(x) dx$, hence you get $I+J=x+C, \ I-J=\cos x \sin x$, hence you can solve this integral.